# How to use SSL and SASL with irssi under Xenial Xerus?

Tags: security, 16.04, ssl, sasl, irssi

I would like to connect to Freenode with `irssi` using both SSL and SASL. Instructions for using the script `cap_sasl.pl` that worked for older versions of `irssi` now show the following error under Xenial Xerus:

```
19:34 -!- Irssi: Error in script cap_sasl:
19:34 cap_sasl has been unloaded from Irssi 20160323.0008 because it conflicts 
          with the built-in SASL support. See /help network for configuring 
          SASL or read the ChangeLog for more information. at (eval 9) line 52.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xenial Xerus now has a newer version of `irssi`:

```
andrew@athens:~$ irssi --version
irssi 0.8.19 (20160323 0008)
```

This version has built-in support for SASL and has been set to reject the `cap_sasl.pl` script with the error message in the question. Easy enough to fix by closing `irssi` and removing the script and links to it:

```
mv -v $HOME/.irssi/scripts/cap_sasl.pl $HOME/.irssi/scripts/cap_sasl.pl_bak    
rm -v $HOME/.irssi/scripts/autorun/cap_sasl.pl
```

Then set yourself up with Freenode using both SSL and the built-in SASL with these commands from within `irssi`. First remove any mention of Freenode and the 'conventional' port (this comes preconfigured with a fresh installation of Ubuntu and `irssi`):

```
/SERVER REMOVE chat.freenode.net 6667 Freenode
/NETWORK REMOVE Freenode
```

Then add an autoconnect to Freenode with the SSL settings and appropriate SSL port:

```
/SERVER ADD -auto -ssl -ssl_verify -ssl_capath /etc/ssl/certs -network Freenode irc.freenode.net 6697
```

Now add the SASL settings, making the appropriate changes for *your* username and password (and omitting the brackets of course):

```
/NETWORK ADD -sasl_mechanism plain -sasl_username <username> -sasl_password <password> Freenode
```

When this is done issue the following commands from within `irssi`:

```
/save
/exit
```

And when you restart `irssi` you should see the following 2 messages flashing by:

1. `20:31 -!- SASL authentication succeeded` = successful SASL authentication
2. `20:31 -!- Mode change [+Zi] for user andrew` = successful SSL connection

Now type in `/join #ubuntu` and you are in the thick of it :)